# how would I pull the data out of the database and re-check the checkboxes that were originally checked and submitted?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I entered checkbox values into the database using the code below.  When a user wants to view the checked boxes at a later time, how would I pull the data out of the database and re-check the checkboxes that were originally checked and submitted?

From the code below the data gets entered like this: DATA1|DATA2|DATA3|

```
var checkbox_value = "";
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (ischecked) {
            checkbox_value += $(this).val() + "|";
        }
    });
```

Now how to I take DATA1|DATA2|DATA3| and re-check the corresponding checkboxes?

Here is how I'm getting other data and re-displaying it from normal input text boxes:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/example/example.php',
  data: "findval="+carrier+"&column="+column,
  dataType: 'json',                
  success: function(data)         
  {

    var auto_id = data['id'];
    var auto_name = data['name'];
    var auto_address = data['address'];
    var auto_trailer_types = data['trailer_types'];

$('#output_autocomplete_forms').html("<form id='example' class='form-horizontal'><input type='hidden' name='auto_id' id='auto_id' class='form-control' value="+auto_id+">......<div class='form-group'>
<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' name='trailer_kinds[]' value='DATA1'>DATA1</label></div>
<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' name='trailer_kinds[]' value='DATA2'>DATA2</label></div>
<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' name='trailer_kinds[]' value='DATA3'>DATA3</label></div>
```

var auto_trailer_types = data['trailer_types'];

Now how do I take DATA1|DATA2|DATA3| and re-check the corresponding checkboxes?

Comment: You could use AJAX to send that string to the database. Similarly you could use AJAX to retrieve it (or get it at execution time on the server if you prefer) and split the values by the `|` and set the checked property of the checkboxes which hold those values. I would suggest you use a more standard format for holding the data though, JSON would probably be the best choice.

Comment: could you show me how to split the values and set the checked property?  Do I do something like the php explode then do an if statement within the checkbox attribute?

Comment: Did my answer help you to solve your problem? If so, please click the checkmark to accept the answer and, optionally, click the up arrow to upvote it if you think that is justified. *Otherwise, please provide feedback about how we can help you further, either by leaving a comment below my answer, or by editing your question and providing more information.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am guessing that the string stored in the database is something like `0|0|1|0`, and you need to restore the checkboxes to that state.

As has been said, you can use AJAX for that. First, you need a trigger to launch the AJAX routine -- a button click, usually:

```
<button id="mybutt">Update Checkboxes</button>
```

Your AJAX routine will look something like this:

```
var rowID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
alert(rowID); //this datum must allow you to identify the row in the database
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'another_php_file.php',
    data: 'id=' +rowID,
    success: function(recd){
        var arrCB = recd.split('|');
        for (var n=0; n<arrCB.length; n++){
            var z = n+1;
            $('#cb'+ z).val( arrCB[n] );
        }
    }
});
```

**another_php_file.php:**

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $pseudo_query = "SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` = '$id' ";

    echo $pseudo_query_result;
```

The `pseudo_query_result` that you echo should be your original `0|0|1|0`. The PHP `echo` sends that datum back to the jQuery AJAX routine's `success` function. *Important: the received data is not available outside that success function. You must do what you want with that data inside the success function, as shown in above example.*

In above code, `.split()` was used to turn the `0|0|1|0` string into an array, and then we use a for loop (or even just manually code each checkbox update individually).

Comment: I don't quite understand what this line of code is doing: $('#cb'+ z).val( arrCB[n] );  Can you break it down?  I think I'm supposed to take a value from the array that I got from the split, then see if it matches the value of the input?  I just don't know how I go from getting this: var arrCB = recd.split('|');  ...  which gives me this ... arrCB ["DATA1","DATA2","DATA3"], then go though the input fields that look like <input type='checkbox' name='trailer_kinds[]' value='DATA1'>...etc, and determine if it needs to be checked or not.  Thanks!

Comment: In the for loop, `n` gets incremented `.length` times. Initially, `n` = 0, so the first time through the loop that line reads: `Inject the first value (element zero) of the array called arrCB into the element with ID="#cb1"`. arrCB is created by `split()`ing the string received via ajax, which should look like this: `0|0|1|0`. Therefore, array arrCB should look like this: [0][0][1][0] -- since arrays are zero-based, `arrCB[0] = 0`, `arrCB[1] = 0`, `arrCB[2] = 1`, etc

Comment: Note that I added ID attributes to your checkboxes to make it easier to target them. Without IDs, you will have have to [do something like `$(':checkbox:eq(n)').val()`](https://jsfiddle.net/fotjwd06/) (to choose the nth checkbox). Much easier to use IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to resolve this issue. But before try to encode your `php` query response in `JSON`

```
$.ajax({
url: "test.php" //Your request URI
 }).done(function(data) { 
   //data (you can name it whatever you want) is the data that you get from your request.
   //eg. if(data.checkbock){ //do something }
 });
```

More informations [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: So if  var auto_trailer_types = data['trailer_types']; gives me back DATA1|DATA2|DATA3|...do I explode those into an array and then do an if statement within each checkbox to see if the data corresponds, then check it or dont?